# help: |22|error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(const char*)' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++

```
int SafeCapture (const char errorChar[50]);

int main(){
    int dimention, dimLimChar;
    char str[50];
    dimention = SafeCapture;

    cout << "-------------------------------------------------\n"
         << "This console application draws some figures like\n"
         << "hourglass, rhomb, bow and a rummer. Both of them\n"
         << "shows filled or void.\n"
         << "-------------------------------------------------\n\n";

    dimLimChar = sprintf(str, "The next request needs a number between %d and %d.", DIMMIN, DIMMAX);

}

#include <limits>

int SafeCapture (const char errorChar[50]){

    int dimention;

    while (true){
        cout << "\nPlease, enter the dimention what you want: ";
        cin >> dimention;

        if (cin.bad()){
            cout << "UNRECOVERABLE SYSTEM FAIL: Console application will close now.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        if (cin.fail()){
            cout << "ERROR, This is not a number... Please try again.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    return dimention;
}
```

Comment: Hola Jesus, por favor añade detalles a tu pregunta. Tal y como está redactada ahora es de muy baja calidad. Edita la pregunta y añade detalles como ¿qué hace ese código? ¿qué error recibes y dónde? ¿que resultado obtienes? ¿qué resultado esperabas obtener? Te recomiendo leer [ask] en el centro de ayuda, y completar el [tour] para conocer cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: Un poco de *contexto* siempre viene bien: que quieres hacer y tal. *P'a* alargar un poco la respuesta, y *echarte una mano* en lo posible: recomendaciones, buenas prácticas, otros *errorcillos* que tengas por ahí, ... en fín :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
dimention = SafeCapture( str );
```

<sub>Siguiendo el estilo *minimalista* de la pregunta ;-)</sub>